# How to use ftsearch command with RedisDataSource in Quarkus?

Tags: quarkus, redis-search

I want to discover how to use the search module of Redis with Quarkus.

So, first I lauched a Redis-stack-server in a Docker. In this instance, I created an index :

```
ft.create idx:voiture on hash prefix 1 voiture:dyn: schema pk numeric sortable voie tag sortable
```

Then I added some datas :

```
hmset voiture:dyn:001 pk 10 voie c8l2
hmset voiture:dyn:002 pk 22 voie c8l2
hmset voiture:dyn:003 pk 10 voie c9l2
hmset voiture:dyn:004 pk 14 voie c8l2
```

Finally I checked with a test

```
ft.search idx:voiture "@voie:{c8l2} pk:[8 16]"
```

And it works, Redis answered with voiture:dyn:001 and voiture:dyn:004

So I wrote code to reproduce the check in Quarkus

The code I wrote is the following :

```
package org.acme.data;

import io.quarkus.redis.datasource.RedisDataSource;
import io.quarkus.redis.datasource.search.Document;
import io.quarkus.redis.datasource.search.SearchCommands;
import io.quarkus.redis.datasource.search.SearchQueryResponse;
import jakarta.inject.Singleton;

import static io.smallrye.config.ConfigLogging.log;


@Singleton
public class RedisOperation {

    private final SearchCommands<String> searchc;

    public RedisOperation(RedisDataSource ds) {
        searchc = ds.search(String.class);
    }


    public String getIndex(String idVoie,Integer pkDebut,Integer pkFin) {
        String index = "idx:voiture";
        String query = "@voie:{"+idVoie+"} @pk:["+pkDebut+" "+pkFin+"]";
        
        StringBuilder retour = new StringBuilder("");

        log.info("On envoie la demande de recherche sur "+index+" avec la query : "+query);
        SearchQueryResponse result = searchc.ftSearch(index, query);
        
        log.info("la requête est passée");
        log.info("La réponse est : "+result.toString());
        for (Document doc : result.documents()) {
            log.info("Trouver : "+doc.key());
            retour.append(" ").append(doc.key());
        }
        return retour.toString();
    }
}
```

I expected to have the same result that the one I had directly in Redis. Instead of this I add the following error :

> 2024-01-19 11:00:25,534 INFO  [io.sma.config] (executor-thread-1) On envoie la demande de recherche sur idx:voiture avec la query : @voie:{c8l2} @pk:[8 16]
> 2024-01-19 11:00:25,540 ERROR [io.qua.ver.htt.run.QuarkusErrorHandler] (executor-thread-1) HTTP Request to /referentiel/check failed, error id: f0f17a00-4995-4b84-890c-95e6a7ad3a4d-3: java.lang.RuntimeException: Multi is a Map
> at io.vertx.redis.client.impl.types.MultiType.get(MultiType.java:114)
> at io.vertx.mutiny.redis.client.Response.get(Response.java:189)
> at io.quarkus.redis.runtime.datasource.ReactiveSearchCommandsImpl.decodeSearchQueryResult(ReactiveSearchCommandsImpl.java:188)
> at io.quarkus.redis.runtime.datasource.ReactiveSearchCommandsImpl.lambda$ftSearch$7(ReactiveSearchCommandsImpl.java:181)
> at io.smallrye.context.impl.wrappers.SlowContextualFunction.apply(SlowContextualFunction.java:21)
> at io.smallrye.mutiny.operators.uni.UniOnItemTransform$UniOnItemTransformProcessor.onItem(UniOnItemTransform.java:36)
> at io.smallrye.mutiny.vertx.AsyncResultUni.lambda$subscribe$1(AsyncResultUni.java:35)
> at io.smallrye.mutiny.vertx.DelegatingHandler.handle(DelegatingHandler.java:25)
> at io.quarkus.redis.runtime.client.ObservableRedis.lambda$send$1(ObservableRedis.java:54)
> at io.vertx.core.impl.future.FutureImpl$3.onSuccess(FutureImpl.java:141)
> at io.vertx.core.impl.future.FutureBase.emitSuccess(FutureBase.java:60)
> at io.vertx.core.impl.future.FutureImpl.tryComplete(FutureImpl.java:211)
> at io.vertx.core.impl.future.Composition$1.onSuccess(Composition.java:62)
> at io.vertx.core.impl.future.FutureBase.emitSuccess(FutureBase.java:60)
> at io.vertx.core.impl.future.FutureImpl.tryComplete(FutureImpl.java:211)
> at io.vertx.core.impl.future.Eventually$1.onSuccess(Eventually.java:44)
> at io.vertx.core.impl.future.FutureBase.emitSuccess(FutureBase.java:60)
> at io.vertx.core.impl.future.SucceededFuture.addListener(SucceededFuture.java:88)
> at io.vertx.core.impl.future.Eventually.onSuccess(Eventually.java:41)
> at io.vertx.core.impl.future.FutureBase.emitSuccess(FutureBase.java:60)
> at io.vertx.core.impl.future.FutureImpl.tryComplete(FutureImpl.java:211)
> at io.vertx.core.impl.future.Transformation$1.onSuccess(Transformation.java:63)
> at io.vertx.core.impl.future.FutureBase.emitSuccess(FutureBase.java:60)
> at io.vertx.core.impl.future.FutureImpl.addListener(FutureImpl.java:196)
> at io.vertx.core.impl.future.PromiseImpl.addListener(PromiseImpl.java:23)
> at io.vertx.core.impl.future.Transformation.onSuccess(Transformation.java:44)
> at io.vertx.core.impl.future.FutureBase.emitSuccess(FutureBase.java:60)
> at io.vertx.core.impl.future.FutureImpl.tryComplete(FutureImpl.java:211)
> at io.vertx.core.impl.future.PromiseImpl.tryComplete(PromiseImpl.java:23)
> at io.vertx.redis.client.impl.RedisStandaloneConnection.handle(RedisStandaloneConnection.java:417)
> at io.vertx.redis.client.impl.RESPParser.handleResponse(RESPParser.java:296)
> at io.vertx.redis.client.impl.RESPParser.handleMulti(RESPParser.java:262)
> at io.vertx.redis.client.impl.RESPParser.handle(RESPParser.java:102)
> at io.vertx.redis.client.impl.RESPParser.handle(RESPParser.java:24)
> at io.vertx.core.net.impl.NetSocketImpl.lambda$new$1(NetSocketImpl.java:101)
> at io.vertx.core.streams.impl.InboundBuffer.handleEvent(InboundBuffer.java:255)
> at io.vertx.core.streams.impl.InboundBuffer.write(InboundBuffer.java:134)
> at io.vertx.core.net.impl.NetSocketImpl$DataMessageHandler.handle(NetSocketImpl.java:402)
> at io.vertx.core.impl.EventLoopContext.emit(EventLoopContext.java:55)
> at io.vertx.core.impl.DuplicatedContext.emit(DuplicatedContext.java:179)
> at io.vertx.core.net.impl.NetSocketImpl.handleMessage(NetSocketImpl.java:378)
> at io.vertx.core.net.impl.ConnectionBase.read(ConnectionBase.java:159)
> at io.vertx.core.net.impl.VertxHandler.channelRead(VertxHandler.java:153)
> at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:442)
> at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:420)
> at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:412)
> at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1410)
> at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:440)
> at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:420)
> at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:919)
> at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:166)
> at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:788)
> at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:724)
> at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:650)
> at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:562)
> at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:997)
> at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
> at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
> at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)

Does Someone can tell me what I did wrong ? I expect it is the query parameter which is not OK but I found non documentation on it.

Thanks for your help !